# Patron factory method, por que debo crear las interfaces?

Tags: java, arquitectura-de-software

Tengo este codigo, que es la implementacion del patron factory method
lo saque de aqui https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_Method_(patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o)

```
abstract class Creator{
    // Definimos método abstracto
    public abstract Product factoryMethod();
}
```

Ahora definimos el creador concreto:

```
public class ConcreteCreator extends Creator{
    public Product factoryMethod() {
        return new ConcreteProduct();
    }
}
```

Definimos el producto y su implementación concreta:

```
public interface Product{
    public void operacion();
}

public class ConcreteProduct implements Product{
    public void operacion(){
        System.out.println("Una operación de este producto");
    }
}
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Creator aCreator;
    aCreator = new ConcreteCreator();
    Product producto = aCreator.factoryMethod();
    producto.operacion();
}
```

no entiendo la utilidad de crear la clase abstracta Creator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dicen que los japoneses no trabajan para sí mismos, sino para sus nietos.
El patrón *factory* aplica ese tipo de visión a largo plazo, para las generaciones futuras -herencia-.

La idea general del factory es definir un ***creador*** de **algo**, y eso lo podrías implementar sin interface ni clase abstracta y sólo tú sabrías que es un factory; por el contrario, y pensando en futuras subclases, el *Patrón Factory* modela ***creadores*** de **productos** que **hacen algo**.

Implementar la clase abstracta permite a la subclase definirse -e identificarse- como un **creador** mediante el uso de cierto método abstracto. 
En contraparte, la interfase permite definirse como "hacedor de **algo**".

Cabe notar que con *genéricos* -como en java- éste patrón puede tomar formas distintas.

Answer (score 1):

A fin de cuentas, un abstract sirve para agrupar métodos y parámetros comunes entre clases que tienen algunas diferencias y a la vez impedir que se cree instancias de estes.

---

Imagínate que tienes otra clase llamada `SlabsCreator` que comparte con tu `ConcreteCreator` ciertos parámetros y métodos que son comunes para ambos, pero sin embargo tienen otros que son distintos. Vamos a suponer que ambos tienen en común las variables `alto, ancho, altura, material` y los métodos `superficie,area`

Lo que son la parte común, lo meterías dentro de tu clase abstracta `creator` y esta estaría disponible para los hijos.

---

Bien, te acabo de explicar la herencia. Ahora toca explicarte la utilidad del abstract.

Si tu clase `creator` no fuese abstracta, se podria crear instancias de esta. El hacerla abstracta es la forma de impedirlo. Te sirve para forzar a que las instancias sean de `ConcreteCreator` o `SlabsCreator`

---

También te sirve el agrupar ambas clases bajo un abstract  para cuando se hace referencia a estos y no se sabe si es de un tipo o otro. Imaginemos que tenemos una clase llamada `Building` y esta tendrá un parámetro `Creator material;` ya que este objeto puede estar compuesto de uno de los dos creators, pero no sabes cual es.

Si `creator` no fuese abstracta, se podría hacer un `Creator material = new Creator();`
Si las dos clases no heredasen de `creator` tendrías que tener un parametro para cada clase.

---

Espero que se entienda lo que quiero decir